# Cloud Functions for Firebase doesn't recognize changes in updated index.js file

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

In other words, functions deployments seems not working for me. I made some changes in the index.js file and redeployed the function, it says deployment successful and Firebase log shows a deployment was made, but the newer code won't take effect.

It kept hold on the the first deployment of the function and still operates on that code. I even deployed with errors in code and all kinds of stuff like redeploying whole project, functions only, re-initializing Firebase CLI, npm but no luck.

Anybody had this issue before or just me because I'm on free spark?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in this site. I cannot know what changes you made to the `index.js` file could you please provide the new code that you implemented? so we can try to fix it.

Comment: not sure what you talking about? I mean index.js of my test project in firebase account and thats not the problem. Problem is any change you deploy it doesn't take effect in firebase funciton.

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you without seeing your code. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)